# What is the cleanest way to direct wxWidgets to always use wxFileConfig?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am writing my first serious wxWidgets program. I'd like to use the wxConfig facility to make the program's user options persistent. However I *don't* want wxConfigBase to automatically use the Windows registry. Even though I'm initially targeting Windows, I'd prefer to use a configuration (eg .ini) file. Does anyone know a clean and simple way of doing this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source of [wx/config.h](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/include/wx/config.h) file, all you need is to define the **`wxUSE_CONFIG_NATIVE`** symbol to 0 in your project and then it will always use `wxFileConfig`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it didn't quite work exactly but did point me in the right direction. Instead of undefining wxUSE_CONFIG_NATIVE, redefining wxUSE_CONFIG_NATIVE from its default of 1 to 0 instead does work.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest and simplest way is to use wxFileConfig class.